# How to extract the index from pd.Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, extract

I have some Dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':  ['Alice','John','Peter','Richard'],
    'age':  [23,28,43,29],
    'gender': [0,1,1,1],
    'salary': [900, 400, 900, 400]
})
```

I can extract any value from this

```
df.ix[df['name'] == 'Alice', 'salary']
0    900
Name: salary, dtype: int64
```

though I want to extract just the index

```
0
df.ix[df['name'] == 'Alice', index] 
df.ix[df['name'] == 'Alice', df.index]
```

i get an error

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df[df['name'] == 'Alice'].index)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

print (df.index[df['name'] == 'Alice'])
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

If need output as `list`:

```
print (df[df['name'] == 'Alice'].index.tolist())
[0]
```

And if need select first value of list:

```
print (df[df['name'] == 'Alice'].index[0])
0
```

Comment: thnx a lot! last - what i need!